Expanding $x(t+dt)$ using the Taylor series and then re-expressing the series in terms of different increments
This is related to this question. Suppose we have the following relation:
$$ \left \{ \frac{d}{ds} x(s) = \chi(x(s)) \frac{dM(t)}{dt} \right \}_{s=t}. \tag{2.40}$$
In the above, $\chi(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$. Given the relation above, the author of the paper writes the following:
$$x(t + dt) = \exp(dt \partial_s) x(s) |_{s=t} = \exp(\chi(x)dM(t)\partial_x)x|_{x=x(t)},$$
where $\partial_u \equiv \partial / \partial u$.
I understand that $\exp(dt \partial_s) x(s) |_{s=t}$ is just the Taylor expansion of $x(t+dt)$ around $t$. However, I don't understand how to get to $\exp(\chi(x)dM(t)\partial_x)x|_{x=x(t)}$.
